# How to write unit tests for stored procedures in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, stored-procedures

I am working on a project where we use lots of stored procedures. Currently, we unit test stored procedures by:

1) Writing a sql script that calls the stored procedure and uses select statements to print output values.

2) Then by comparing a good output with the test output for declaring whether the test has passed or not.

Is there an inbuilt support for Unit Testing in MySQL? What is the industry standard way of doing this?